# class textFormField extends

Tags: flutter

tengo una clase que se llama CustomTextFormField y necesito hacer una clase que extienda de esta e incorpore nuevas propiedades. Como por ejemplo que la subclase tenga el inputFormatters para cargar una funcionalidad.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const CustomTextFormField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        isDense: true,
        counterText: '',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

bueno espero que le sirva a alguien, he aquí el código de la clase que logré

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomTextFormFieldUpper extends CustomTextFormField {
  CustomTextFormFieldUpper({
    super.key,
    required TextEditingController controller,
    FocusNode? focusNode,
    bool obscureText = false,
    String? hint,
    String? labelText,
    IconData? decorationIcon,
    IconData? prefixIcon,
    TextCapitalization? textCapitalization,
    Color? backColor,
    Color? foreColor,
    String? errorMessage,
    Function(String)? onChanged,
    String? Function(String?)? validator,
    int? maxLength,
  }) : super(
          inputFormatters: [
            UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
          ],
          controller: controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          obscureText: obscureText,
          hint: hint,
          labelText: labelText,
          decorationIcon: decorationIcon,
          prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
          textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
          backColor: backColor,
          foreColor: foreColor,
          errorMessage: errorMessage,
          onChanged: onChanged,
          validator: validator,
          maxLength: maxLength,
        );
}

// TODO: esta es la clase PADRE
class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final bool obscureText;
  final String? hint;
  final String? labelText;
  final IconData? decorationIcon;
  final IconData? prefixIcon;
  final TextCapitalization? textCapitalization;
  final Color? backColor;
  final Color? foreColor;
  final String? errorMessage;
  final Function(String)? onChanged;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final int? maxLength;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;

  const CustomTextFormField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    this.focusNode,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.hint,
    this.labelText,
    this.decorationIcon,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.textCapitalization,
    this.backColor,
    this.foreColor,
    this.errorMessage,
    this.onChanged,
    this.validator,
    this.maxLength,
    this.inputFormatters,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    final border = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    );

    return TextFormField(
      maxLength: maxLength,
      controller: controller,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      validator: validator,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      textCapitalization: textCapitalization ?? TextCapitalization.none,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: foreColor ?? colors.onSurface),
            inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        fillColor: backColor ?? colors.background,
        filled: true,
        enabledBorder: border,
        focusedBorder: border.copyWith(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: colors.primary),
        ),
        errorBorder: border.copyWith(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: border.copyWith(borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 33, 33))),
        isDense: true,
        hintText: hint,
        labelText: labelText,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          color: foreColor ?? colors.onBackground,
        ),
        focusColor: colors.primary,
        errorText: errorMessage,
        counterText: '',
        icon: decorationIcon != null ? Icon(decorationIcon) : null,
        prefixIcon: prefixIcon != null ? Icon(prefixIcon) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Además de aclarar en la pregunta cuál fue el problema en cuestión, pulsa en [edit] para describir cómo este código responde a tu pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.